# required field html 5 dont work on android Web browser

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to figure out why it does not work for me following code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>myTestForm</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="ok" method="post" id="myform">
<p>
<input name="user_name" type="text" required id="user_name">
 </p>
<p>
<input name="user_password" type="password" required id="user_password">
</p>
<input name="sumbit" type="submit" id="sumbit" value="send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to test it with Chrome or Android Dolphin Browser but it does not work
It works only on normal computer In most browsers

Anyone know why it does not work  ? Is there a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

The **required** attribute only works on android versions < 2.3.

http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html

Basic javascript validation using jQuery :

```
$('[required]').on('blur', function () {
    if (!$(this).val().length) { // check if the value is empty
        // Could do an alert or something else
    }
});
```

Comment: You could use a javascript validation library or make your own javascript validation (see update in answer). Or you could just do this validation on the server.